# How do I get current route and params from different places in my application?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my component where routing is occurring (and where router outlet resides), I'm able to use ActivatedRoute just like usual, but I have a component that stays static between route changes, and it needs to know the current route and route parameters. In the Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html), it says:

> You can access the current RouterState from anywhere in the
>   application using the Router service and the routerState property.

But I'm not sure the page explains just how to do that. It doesn't mention a routerState property anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you inject `ActivatedRoute` to your static component:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
```

You then can listen to route params or query params changes by subscribing to the two corresponding `Observable` in `ActivatedRoute`. By this way, the static component will always be updated with the latest route parameters.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {console.log(params);});
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(qParams => {console.log(qParams);});
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. By the way, this was only a second choice to trying to have my main service contain the router. I posted about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41798608/how-do-i-get-current-route-and-params-from-different-places-in-my-application.